# laravel add form data to auth registration

Tags: laravel, authentication

how would you go about adding custom fields to the laravel auth registration process. I would like to check which country they're from. I was going to add it to register controller but I'm not sure how to pass the array to the view. and when i do add it to the controller it throws up and error. Any advice would be wonderful.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you will need to add a column on the users table to store this information. You can do this with a migration. Put something like this into the `up()` function.

```php
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('country');
});
```

Next you will need to add it to the `$fillable` array in `User.php` like this, so that the value provided will be saved.

```php
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'country'
];
```

Then you should add it to the create function in `RegisterController` like this. This will connect the value that the user provided with the new User object that will be saved.

```php
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'country' => $data['country'],
    ]);
}
```

You will also need to add it to `register.blade.php` so the user can provide the information.

```
<label for="countryInput" class="col-md-4 control-label">Country</label>
<input id="countryInput" type="text" class="form-control" name="country">
```

Finally, if you want to validate this field you should add it in the validator function (in the `RegisterController`).